# Using H2 SQL convert PRIMARY KEY into IDENTITY

Tags: sql, h2

I have an H2 (V1.4.196) table with a PRIMARY KEY. I now wish to be able to add an extra column with an auto-incremented value in the primary key. In short I need to change the PRIMARY KEY column into an IDENTITY column.
Doing

```
ALTER TABLE trains ALTER COLUMN trno smallint IDENTITY
```

Changed trno into a BigInt!

OK, second attempt at editing (the first seemed to get dropped).
Checking back I see that the original table was actually created without a PRIMARY KEY, so:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 (trNo smallint, stuff int)
ALTER TABLE t3 ALTER COLUMN trNo smallint IDENTITY
```

Does indeed change trNo into a BigInt! I assume this is a bug in H2.

Using my more recent software (the tables are created and edited automatically)

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (trNo smallint PRIMARY KEY, stuff int)
ALTER TABLE t2 ALTER COLUMN trno smallint IDENTITY
```

Gave: JdbcSQLException: Attempt to define a second primary key

The documentation lists IDENTITY as a valid option in ALTER COLUMN.

I have since found that

```
ALTER TABLE t2 ALTER COLUMN trno smallint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Does what I want but that was just trying to figure out a way around the problem rather than following any useful guidance. Is IDENTITY just an alias for 'PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT'? Some web pages suggest IDENTITY only means 'NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' so I am confused.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example, with JDBC URL and `create table` statement?

Comment: `IDENTITY` is equivalent to `BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` so the `SMALLINT` type is discarded.